# Why getUnixTime fuction from date-fns returns 1970?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date-fns

```
import { format, getUnixTime } from "date-fns";

import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [unixTime, setUnixTime] = useState(Date.now());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={format(unixTime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")}
        onChange={(e) => setUnixTime(getUnixTime(new Date(e.target.value)))}
        type="datetime-local"
      />
      <p>{format(unixTime, "PPp")}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above code, when you change the date by selecting a date in the input field the date does not become the date that you selected but rather became Jan 20 1970. here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-date-fns-code-iwvkms) (try select the date in the input field so you can see what i meant).

How to get the date that was selected?

Answer (score 3):

You need to multiply the timestamp by a factor of `1000`.

`setUnixTime(getUnixTime(new Date(e.target.value)) * 1000)`.

This is because JS timestamps are kept in milliseconds as opposed to Unix timestamps which use seconds.